# select/click link in table in R Web scraping through RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am learning Web scraping through RSelenium and I having problem to click the link in a table. Here is the sample code showing my problem

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
gc()

library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="106.0.5249.21")
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$navigate("http://delcorealestate.co.delaware.pa.us/pt/search/commonsearch.aspx?mode=address")

Agree_button <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = "btAgree")
Agree_button$clickElement()

AddDA  <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2), number = c("30", "3"), street = c("HIGHVIEW DR","FOREST RD"))

for (i in 1:nrow(AddDA)) {
  
  CurrID     <- AddDA$ID[i]
  CurrNumber <- AddDA$number[i]
  CurrStreet <- AddDA$street[i] 
      
  # Mimic the process of input N umber and Street
  Number_textfield <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'inpNumber')
  Number_textfield$sendKeysToElement(list(CurrNumber))
  
  Street_textfield <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'inpStreet')
  Street_textfield$sendKeysToElement(list(CurrStreet))
  
  Search_button <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = "btSearch")
  Search_button$clickElement()
  
  Sys.sleep(5)
  
  # for ID =2, it will return multiple address and I need to select the one I need, but I donot know how to do it
  # element <-  remote_driver$findElement(using = "link text", value = "FOREST RD 3") %>% clickElement()   #  SearchResults
  # element <-  remote_driver$findElement(using = "class", value = "SearchResults") %>% clickElement()   #  SearchResults

  # check all the tables and save the data for current step
  # and them go back the search page and do next loop
  
  # here is the step to go back to the search page for next loop
  r_dropdown <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "link text", value = "Property Search Home")
  remote_driver$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = r_dropdown)
  remote_driver$findElement(using = "link text", value = "Search by Address")$clickElement() 
  
}
```

In above code, when I run ID =1, everything is good and I got to the page/that I need, as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlfoR.png)

But for ID =2, it will return multiple addresses, and I need to select the 'FOREST RD 3' to open that link and go to a page similar to what I got when I ran ID =1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guc6h.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfFvE.png)

I have two questions here:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlfoR.png) how to select the 'FOREST RD 3'. I right-clicked the page, and 'Inspect' the element, I can see 'FOREST RD 3' there but didnot find href.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guc6h.png) how to add a if-checking inside of the loop, so the code can handle different cases, i.e., return with only one address (e.g, ID =1) , or multiple address (eg., ID) where I need to select the right one before I extract the data

I am new to RSelenium and I tried to google the solution, but unsuccessful. I wish someone could help me on this matter and would really appreciate that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a dynamic table, so I would just use xpath to search for the address.
To check whether there are multiple search results you can look at the current url after doing the search.

```
  #from your code
  Search_button <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = "btSearch")
  Search_button$clickElement()
  
  Sys.sleep(5)
  
  #checking if the url has "search/CommonSearch" in it
  current_url <- unlist(remote_driver$getCurrentUrl())
  multiple_results <- str_detect(current_url, "search/CommonSearch")
  
  #if there are multiple results, we select the correct one
  if(multiple_results) {
    
    #first we need to combine the street name and number for the search term
    search_term <- paste(CurrStreet, CurrNumber, sep = " ")  
    
    #create xpath
    xpath_input <- paste0("//*[text()='", search_term, "']")
    
    #finding the correct row
    correct_row <- remote_driver$findElement("xpath", xpath_input)
    
    #click row
    correct_row$clickElement()
  }
```